# Identifying datetime format for extracting date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, strftime

I have a time data in the following format. I am trying to extract date only from it. But I am confused what format is that.

2019-04-30 16:24:26.7913438 -04:00

I tried '%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%f', but didn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: The [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) function has a `infer_datetime_format` parameter, it might be worth giving that a try, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I just had to put utc=True, and it worked magic.

```
pd.to_datetime(a['AdmissionD'], utc=True).dt.date
```

Thank you!